# Cannot insert jquery code (if-else) in .html()

Tags: jquery

Cannot insert jquery code (if-else) in .html(). Please help.

```
abc.html(

'<b>Drink: </b>'+
'+ if (results.cola == 1) {"Cola"} +'
'+ if (results.fanta == 1) {"Fanta"} +'
'+ if (results.sprite == 1) {"Sprite"} +'
'<hr>'
       );
```

Comment: A new language was born ?

Comment: can you post full code, markup also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `if` statements as expressions. To use `if` statements you would put the string together before you use it:

```
var html = '<b>Drink: </b>';
if (results.cola == 1) html += 'Cola';
if (results.fanta == 1) html += 'Fanta';
if (results.sprite == 1) html += 'Sprite';
html += '<hr>';

bc.html(html);
```

You can use the conditional operator in an expression:

```
abc.html(
  '<b>Drink: </b>'+
  (results.cola == 1 ? 'Cola' : '') +
  (results.fanta == 1 ? 'Fanta' : ''} +
  (results.sprite == 1 ? 'Sprite' : ''} +
  '<hr>'
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this :

```
abc.html('<b>Drink: </b>'+    (results.cola == 1?"Cola" :"") +    (results.fanta == 1?"fanta " :"") +    (results.sprite == 1?"sprite " :"") +    '<hr>' );
```

or

```
abc.html('<b>Drink: </b>'+   
 (results.cola== 1?"Cola" :"") +   
 (results.fanta == 1?"fanta " :"") +    
(results.sprite  == 1?"sprite " :"") +   
 '<hr>' );
```